# how to write seperate controllers for rails single page app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am creating list of forms say

```
Questions form  
Answers form  
Hints form
```

All these have different controller and view, question_controller , answers_controller, hints_controller.

Now I need to fetch all these views in tabbed UI in home page (say home_controller , home#index)

I tried **render : partial ,render  :template** also with **locals** , I can't achieve.

It can be easily done by moving all the object to same controller ( home_controller , but i am not sure about this approach , since it will make home controller too complicated to manage ) , but I need to keep this in separate controllers (question_controller , answers_controller, hints_controller) and render it to same page. I am using client side validation, simple form gems.

**Below is my question controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @question = Question.new

    @question_status = []
    @question_mode = []
    @question_type = []

    @question_lookups = Lookup.where({:lookup_for => "question"})

    @question_lookups.each do |lk|
        case lk.lookup_type
            when 'mode'
                @question_mode << lk
            when 'status'
                @question_status << lk
            else
                @question_type << lk
        end
    end

    @caa = Questioncaa.new

end

end
```

**Question View ( with Simple form )**

```
<%= simple_form_for @question, :validate => true do |q| %>
<%= q.input :question_info,  :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :toolbar => 'Easy', :width => 750 }  %> 
<%= q.input :question_source %>
<%= q.input :is_mobile %>
<%= q.input :is_similar_question %>
<%= q.input :is_boss_question %>
<%= q.input :is_racing_question %>
<%= q.input :is_speed_question %>
<%= q.input :difficulty_level %>
<%= q.input :ideal_time %>

<%= q.input :lookups, :collection => @question_mode, :value_method => :id, :label_method => :lookup_value,:prompt => "Choose Mode", :label => :QuestionMode %>
<%= q.input :lookups, :collection => @question_status, :value_method => :id, :label_method => :lookup_value,:prompt => "Choose Status", :label => :QuestionStatus %>
<%= q.input :lookups, :collection => @question_type, :value_method => :id, :label_method => :lookup_value,:prompt => "Choose Type", :label => :QuestionType %>

<%= simple_fields_for @caa do |c| %>
    <%= c.input :needs_hints %>
    <%= c.input :needs_video_solution %>
    <%= c.input :needs_tips_tricks %>
    <%= c.input :needs_formulae %>
    <%= c.input :needs_key_concepts %>
<% end %>


<%= q.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

**Home View**

```
<div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="learning_map">

                <!-- I need to acheive this -->
                <%= render :template => "learning_map/index" %>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="questions">

                <!-- I need to acheive this -->
                <%= render :template => "questions/index", :collection => @question_mode %>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="answers">.

                <!-- I need to acheive this -->
                <%= render :templates => "answers/index" %>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Pls advice me , it will be very helpful. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Take a loot at [Nested layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts), hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should change logic of your templates a little (here is example for 'question' view):

1) split your question template into 2 files: 
- header with form declaration of simple_form_for
- _form.html.erb file with `<%= fields_for @question do |q| %>` and list of your questions fields like `<%= q.input %>`

2) add `<%= render :partial => 'form' %>` in your header file

3) use `<%= render :partial => 'question\form' %>` in your home view template

4) dont forget to initialize @question variable in home_controller.